# Ant do not delete file with no name like .gitignore .git

Tags: ant

I want to use git to delete a folder,the folder contains some file with no name and only have extension,such as ***.gitignore***,***.log***

I did it as below,and I also tried many other ways,but still can not delete them,can anyone help me?Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test" default="clean">
  <target name="clean">
     <delete>
       <fileset dir="E:\test\tmt"/>
     </delete>
  <echo message="Finished delete file"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following snippet...

```
<delete>
    <fileset dir="E:\test\tmt"/>
</delete>
```

...`.gitignore` won't be deleted because `.gitignore` is in Ant's [Default Exclude Set](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes).

You can configure Ant to ignore the Default Exclude Set with the `defaultexcludes` attribute...

```
<delete>
    <fileset dir="E:\test\tmt" defaultexcludes="false"/>
</delete>
```

...or even better, use the following instead...

```
<delete dir="E:\test\tmt"/>
```

`defaultexcludes` isn't needed in this case because the Default Exclude Set only applies to pattern sets such as `<fileset>`.

Comment: I tried **<delete dir="E:\test\tmt"/>** and it success,thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It is deprecated so I would go with Chad's answer, but ant `delete` also has an `excludes` property which takes in a comma-separated list of patterns (or direct file names).  Just FYI.